# Using SQL to find entries that were originally X and later changed to Y

Tags: sql-server

I recently started using SQL for work and don't have much experience of it so I'm sorry if this is a ridiculous question.
I'm looking for an entry that was originally listed as X but was then later changed to Y, I figure that a nested sub query is the way to go but the one I'm trying doesn't seem to use the nested bit.
Here is the code I'm trying

```
    SELECT *
    FROM [HOME].[dba].[ARCHIVE]
    where FRIE like 'AR8%'
    and RESULT = 'X'
    and EXISTS(SELECT FRIE, RESULT
            FROM [HOME].[dba].[ARCHIVE]
            where RESULT = 'Y');
```

Everything as far as the EXISTS works but afterwards it just ignores the nested query

Comment: What defines *later* in your table?

Comment: The subquery is not ignored, it just says " return data if there are any rows in the subquery table where `RESULT = 'Y'`. If there are none, you'd get no rows; if there's 1 or more, you get all of whatever the outer query returns.

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos These entries are circuits that may have been cancelled, X shows that they have had work carried out and Y shows that they are definitely cancelled. So the circuit number will be the same but X may have occured more than once but Y shows that they are out of commision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't have the same WHERE clause in the EXISTS portion.  I think this will work for you:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM [HOME].[dba].[ARCHIVE]
    WHERE FRIE like 'AR8%'
    AND RESULT = 'X'
    AMD EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1
            FROM [HOME].[dba].[ARCHIVE]
            where FRIE like 'AR8%' AND RESULT = 'Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using an INNER JOIN to a subquery rather than using an EXISTS statement.  Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [HOME].[dba].[ARCHIVE] a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT FRIE
                FROM [HOME].[dba].[ARCHIVE]
                WHERE RESULT = 'Y') t1 ON a.FRIE = t1.FRIE
WHERE
    FRIE like 'AR8%'
    and RESULT = 'X'
```

That would return all rows from ARCHIVE where they there is a row with the same FRIE with a RESULT of X and a RESULT of Y.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: While joins are usually better than exists, they aren't in this case, because you could get duplicates if any records went from X to Y to X.  Using exists prevents duplicates - and no join is necessary because we don't care about the columns from the subquery.

Comment: I tried this but it's giving an ambiguous column name for FRIE